# How to configure WCF service to be able satisfy http OR https at same time

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, web-config

I have a silverlight application over WCF. Initially, I am only configure it over http protocol with custom binding. Now, consider different users might have different requirements which will need to use it over https protocol.
I have try to configure two different endpoint with different binding(one use httpTransport, the other one use httpsTransport), but when I run the application in debug mode, it seems like localhost still hosting over https schema(I've somehow managed the localhost to run it in SSL mode, but don't know how to switch it back)
Does anyone has any idea how can I get this work?

Comment: You will need two endpoints - one for http and one for https.  Post your service config file (the `<system.serviceModel>` section), as it sounds like it might be a configuration issue.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that the server side and client side config were not aligned.